# Yii 2 ошибка с bower

Tags: yii2, composer

решил с нуля установить Yii 2 через composer

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

> composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic
>   yii2lesson

получаю

> The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   F:\OpenServer\domains\yii2lesson\vendor\bower/jquery/dist

ладно верю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

bower поставился в папку bower-asset

кроме как ручками перенести нет более изящного метода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое иногда происходит, если вы используете старую версию композитора. Пожалуйста, обновите ваш композитор, а также убедитесь, что вы используете последнюю версию расширения ассета.

```
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```